# Haskell generate increasing pairs sorted by the sum of the elements

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I want to generate a list of pairs that looks like this:

[(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (0,4), (1,3), (0,5) .... ] and so on and so forth.

I made a function that generates ordered pairs

```
orderedPairs = [ (x, y) | x <- [0 .. ], y <- [1 ..], x < y]
```

but I do not know how to go on from here. Thank you. :)

Comment: Make a function to generate the list of pairs for a specific sum first, then use that to get the whole list. If it's not an assignment/exercise you are supposed to learn from, I'll happily elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the hint. I managed to do it like this:

```
orderedPairs n = [ (x, y) | x <- [0 .. n], let y = n - x, x < y]
pairStream n = (orderedPairs n) ++ (pairStream (n + 1))
increasingPairs = pairStream 0
```

take 10 increasingPairs returns the correct output. :)

Comment: Okay, that's a really good start. But instead of filtering out half the list with `x < y`, adjust the upper bound for `x`. ``[(x, n-x) | x <- [0 .. (n-1) `quot` 2]]`` would do that. For `increasingPairs`, you could use `concat [orderedPairs n | n <- [0 .. ]]` or `concatMap orderedPairs [0 .. ]`, or `[0 .. ] >>= orderedPairs`, which I find nicer.

Comment: Yeah, that looks nicer. Thanks for the tips. :D